# How can I browse items of ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> and check their types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote a validation attribute for entire images.
I have two properties (`HttpPostedFileBase`, `ICollection <HttpPostedFileBase>`) . I can check the first but not the second.

```
[MyFileType( " jpg , jpeg , png " )]
public HttpPostedFileBase file128 { get; set; }
public ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> file900 { get; set; }  

public class MyFileTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly List <string> myTypes;
    public MyFileTypeAttribute(string _types)
    {
         MyTypes =_types. Split ( ' ,  ' ).tolist ();
    }
    public override boo Isvalid (object _value)
    {
         if (_value == null )
         {
            return true ; 
         }

         var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtention ((_value as HttpPostedFileBase ).FileName ).Substring (1);
         return MyTypes. Contains ( fileExt , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage (string _name)
    {
        return String.Format (" invalid file type .only following types : {0} are supported . " , String.join ("," , MyTypes));
    }
}
```

I can check `HttpPostedFileBase` but how can I browse items of `ICollection <HttpPostedFileBase>` and check their types?

Answer (score 0):

In case of code:

```
[MyFileType( " jpg , jpeg , png " )]
public ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> file900 { get ; set; }
```

attribute regards the collection itself, but you can check within `IsValid` if attribute is specified for collection value. Something like (not tested) code:

```
public override bool Isvalid (object _value)
{
     var col = _value as ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase>;
     if (col != null )
     {
        // check each element; 
        return col.All(x => IsValid(x));
     }
     else
     {
         var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtention((_value as HttpPostedFileBase ).FileName).Substring(1);
         return MyTypes.Contains (fileExt, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
     }
}
```